# Covert a DES 96 bit key to 64 bit

Tags: encryption, des

How can I convert a 96 bit key to a 64 bit key? I have a DES key that is **96 bits long (i.e 745347651281)** . I want to **convert this to 64 bit** which I will use to decrypt a DES ciphertext.

**Update:**

1. There was an "original key" encrypted by RSA
2. The "original key" was decrypted using RSA to give us this (i.e 745347651281)
3. This (i.e 745347651281) is now supposed to be used to decryped a DES
   file.

Note : The "original key" was in hex format which I converted to integer(base 16) before doing RSA decryption.

Comment: Maybe it is Base64 encoded. Otherwise you cannot decrypt the original message. Read about Base64 encoding.

Comment: @i486 `12` is not a valid base 64 character if viewed as ASCII.

Comment: There is no such thing as a  96 bit key for DES. Are you sure it is not 56 bits in size? What language / runtime do you need this for? Remember, this is StackOverflow: programming related questions only! And welcome to StackOverflow of course!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I am using this in python and I need the key to be 8 byte or 64 bit to do decryption. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CodesInChaos my bad for the wrong calculation(96 bits), Wasn't this 12 digits supposed to be 48 bits?

Comment: @basifat If you use uniformly distributed hex digits you get 48 bits, if you restrict it to decimal digits it's only 40 bits.

Comment: @basifat It could be that your library is doing some kind of key expansion inside, please include the code and the crypto library used into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The key you have displayed is 48 bits in size, not 96 bits in size - if it is considered to be specified hexadecimals. A DES key without parity would be 56 bits in size. This means that you have to create the parity bits that are missing. The parity of DES is described as such:

> One bit in each 8-bit byte of the KEY may be utilized for error detection in key generation, distribution, and storage. Bits 8, 16,..., 64 are for use in ensuring that each byte is of odd parity.

Note that the bits are numbered starting at the left with value 1, meaning that the *least* significant bit of each byte is used for parity. So you have to distribute the bits you have been given over the bytes, and then adjust the parity of each byte by possibly flipping the least significant bit (using XOR with 1).

Usually libraries have support for this kind of operation. In Java you can do this by generating the DES key using `SecretKeyFactory` for instance.

Comment: If the key is hex, it's only 12*4=48 bits, not 56.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Right you are, I just expected 56 bits too much I guess. This question is not salvageable without significant edits, I'm going to close this "unclear what you are asking".